# systemd секции, пути

Tags: linux, systemd

Курю systemd. Есть некие секции юнита

```
[Unit]
Description=MyUnit
After=syslog.target
After=network.target
After=nginx.service
After=mysql.service
Requires=mysql.service
Wants=redis.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/work/www/myunit/shared/tmp/pids/service.pid
WorkingDirectory=/work/www/myunit/current

User=myunit
Group=myunit

Environment=RACK_ENV=production

OOMScoreAdjust=-1000

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec service -C /work/www/myunit/shared/config/service.rb --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec service -S /work/www/myunit/shared/tmp/pids/service.state stop
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec service -S /work/www/myunit/shared/tmp/pids/service.state restart
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Секция [Unit] мне полностью понятна.
С секции [Service]начинают возникать проблемы. А именно:

- `PIDFile` - откуда он возьмется? Мне нужно его в своем скрипте явно прописать(как, если он с каждым новым запуском процесса меняется) или systemd каким то образом сам найдет пид процесса который запуститься из скрипта или...в общем мне в целом непонятно про PIDFile. Откуда и что берется и какой путь я должен указать к пиду.
- `WorkingDirectory` - что я должен написать здесь? путь к скрипту или к чему?
- `User` и `Group` - тоже непонятно откуда взялось. Я думаю про текущего пользователя, но тогда мне непонятно почему в примере указано `myunit` . Пользователь типа такой или что это? Здесь пояснения просто нет что за `myunit` такой.
- `Environment` - не понимаю что это и как его правильно указывать и откуда взять.
- `Exec Start`, `Exec Stop`, `Exec Reload` - мне понятно  в целом  что это обработка команд на стоп старт и релод, но здесь не понимаю на какие файлы указывает команда после `exec service`, непонятно чем `-C` отличается от `-C`
- Ну и `Install` тоже не особо понятно. В общем могу предположить, что здесь указание какой пользователь может запустить юнит, но если не правильно догадываюсь, поправьте плз.

Внимание вопрос: кто-то может мне по пунктам обьяснить что  к чему здесь?Учитывая, что я это только сейчас systemd курить начал и еще толком ничего не понял.
Пример взят отсюда

Comment: По-моему, глубоко курить имеет смысл технологии вокруг контейнеров. А systemd так, краем ... ну есть такой слой абстракции, работает (уже не глючит)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **PIDFile** создаётся демоном. Если демон не создаёт такого файла, можно ничего не писать, systemd и без того умеет узнавать активные процессы через cgroups. Однако, без этого файла systemd не сможет определить какой из процессов является главным (в случае, когда их создаётся несколько).
- **WorkingDirectory** - это рабочая директория вашего скрипта. Что это такое - читайте в разделе "работа с файлами" документации к вашему языку программирования, либо в разделе "работа с командной строкой" учебника по linux; к systemd оно отношения не имеет. Если коротко - то эта настройка задаёт чему будет равен путь `.` (точка). Если скрипт никогда не использует относительные пути - эту настройку можно вообще не указывать.
- **User** и **Group** - это учётные данные, с правами которых будет исполняться сервис. Часто для сервиса создают отдельного пользователя и группу, одноименные с самим сервисом.
- **Environment** - это переменные окружения, которые будут переданы сервису. Какие переменные окружения надо передавать - читайте в мануалах к сервису.
- `exec service` и всё, что дальше в настройках **ExecStart**, **ExecStop** и **ExecReload** - это просто параметры, передаваемые в программу `bundle`, которая входит в экосистему языка Ruby. Соответственно, все эти параметры надо искать в документации по Ruby, к systemd они отношения не имеют.
- Наконец, **WantedBy** из секции **[Install]** - это настройка, которая отвечает за автозапуск сервиса. Значение `multi-user.target` - это unit, который активируется при стандартном запуске ОС, соответственно `WantedBy=multi-user.target` означает, что ваш сервис будет запускаться при нормальной загрузке ОС, но не будет запускаться в аналоге "безопасного режима" (`rescue.target`) и других особых режимах. В большинстве случаев шаблонное `WantedBy=multi-user.target` более чем подходит, но при желании вы можете "прицепить" свой сервис к любому юниту в системе.

Comment: `Какие переменные окружения надо передавать - читайте в мануалах к сервису` - то есть, если я сам пишу сервис, то  я и определяю какие переменные передавать?

Comment: @umd да . . . .

Comment: @umd да. Хотя, иногда переменную может обрабатывать фреймворк. Например, переменная RACK_ENV обрабатывается Rack.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а что будет если я не передам вообще переменных окружения?

Comment: @umd если сервис их не требует, то ничего

Comment: @umd вообще, минимальный сервис-юнит может занимать всего две строки: `[Service]` `ExecStart=/path/to/command` всё остальное опционально и при отсутствии принимает значения по умолчанию